# How come when I type a large number the output just repeats itself over and over?

Tags: c++

How come when I type a large number the output just repeasts itself over and over?

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void convertBinaryToDecimal(string num, MyStack<int>& thestack);
int main() {
    MyStack<int> thestack;
    int input = -22222;
    while (true) {
        cout << "enter -999 to quit, Enter your binarty number: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == -999) { 
            cout << "Thank you, see you next time." << endl;
            system("Pause");
            break; 
        }
        else {
            string str = to_string(input);

            convertBinaryToDecimal(str, thestack);
        }
    }
}
void convertBinaryToDecimal(string num, MyStack<int>& thestack) {
    int remainder = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int dec_value = 0;
    int n;
    stringstream number(num);
    number >> n;

    while (n != 0) {
        remainder = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        dec_value += remainder * pow(2, count);
        count++;
    }
    thestack.push(dec_value);
    int value = thestack.top();
    thestack.pop();
    cout << "The equivalent decimal number is: " << value << endl;
    }
```

.cpp file^

```
#ifndef STACK_H_INCLUDED
#define STACK_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


template<class Type>
class MyStack {
public:

    int count;
    MyStack(int mysize = 100) {
        list = new int[mysize];
        maxStackSize = mysize;
        stackTop = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
    MyStack(const MyStack<Type>& thestack) {
        copyStack(thestack);
    }
    ~MyStack() {
        delete[] list;
    }
    void initializeStack();
    bool isEmptyStack() const;
    bool isFullStack() const;

    Type push(const Type& newItem);
    Type top()const;
    void pop();


    const MyStack<Type>& operator=(const MyStack<Type>& thestack) {
        copyStack(thestack);
        return *(this);
    }


private:
    int maxStackSize;
    int stackTop;
    Type* list;
    void copyStack(const MyStack<Type>&);

};

template<class Type>
void MyStack<Type>::initializeStack() {
    stackTop = 0;
}

template<class Type>
bool MyStack<Type>::isEmptyStack() const {
    return (stackTop == 0);
}

template<class Type>
bool MyStack<Type>::isFullStack() const {
    return (stackTop == maxStackSize);
}

template<class Type>
Type MyStack<Type>::push(const Type& newItem) {
    if (isFullStack()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    list[stackTop] = newItem;
    stackTop++;
    return list[stackTop - 1];
}

template<class Type>
Type MyStack<Type>::top()const {
    if (isEmptyStack()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return list[stackTop - 1];
}

template<class Type>
void MyStack<Type>::pop() {
    if (isEmptyStack()) {

    }
    else {
        stackTop--;
    }

}
template<class Type>
void MyStack<Type>::copyStack(const MyStack<Type>& thestack) {
    delete[] list;
    list = new Type[thestack.maxStackSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < thestack.maxStackSize; i++) {
        list[i] = thestack.list[i];
    }
    stackTop = thestack.stackTop;
    maxStackSize = thestack.maxStackSize;
}


#endif//STACK_H_INCLUDED
```

header file^

When I type a large binary like "101010100100101010" the output repeats itself over and over. When I type a smaller binary like "1010" it's fine and gives me the correct output.

Any ideas? I am pretty sure it just crashes.
Edit: I've been testing it and it breaks after 10 digits.

Comment: There are no checks to make sure `cin >> input;` successfully read a value. Before you debug further you should make sure it did. Do something like `if (cin >> input) { do stuff with input} else { report error and abort program or clear the stream error, clean up the failed input, and ask for a good input. }`. In general, never use an input from anybody until you've made sure it is good input.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I think the main problem ist that you are reading the binary number from a user into an `int` variable. So, if the the user enters 1000, you expect it to be 8, but in reality it is 1000(decimal). Then you convert 1000(decimal) into a string, which is then "1000". That is of course not good and one cause of your problem.

Integer variables can hold values up to a given boundary. You can find out in C++ using

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

The result is machine dependent. A possible value is on a 32bit hardware is: 2147483647

So, now you enter a big string of '1's and '0's, e.g. "101010100100101010" And you expect to read a binary. But you try to put it in an integer. But the decimal number 101010100100101010 will not fit into an integer and so your complete intended functionality will not work as you expect.

The solution is to read the value from the user into a `std::string` and not into an `int`

Then you can convert the binary data in the `std::string` into a decimal.

For that you can use existing build in functions like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string testBinary{"101010100100101010"};
    std::cout << std::stoul(testBinary,0,2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Or a simple conversion with iterating through the string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::string testBinary{"101010100100101010"};

    unsigned long decimalValue{0};
    std::for_each(testBinary.rbegin(),testBinary.rend(), [&decimalValue] (const char& c) { decimalValue |= (c-'0'); decimalValue <<= 1; });
    std::cout << decimalValue << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The stack is not needed at all for this functionality. I am not sure, why you put it in. Maybe for academic purposes.

By the way, you can check for the correctness of a "binary string" with

```
    if (std::all_of(testBinary.begin(), testBinary.end(), [](const char& c){ return c=='1' || c=='0';}))
```